# How to display request data in cakephp beforesave method in model

Tags: before-save

I tried to display request data using $this->data in beforeSave method. But , i don't know why the method is not being called.
How can I display posted data in beforeSave method in cakephp model?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before posting question please read [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Help us to help you.

Comment: I have asked question regarding  cakephp model . A php developer who is on cakephp framework can easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your code in your question.
This displays your entity created/updated :

```
public function beforeSave($event, $entity, $options = array())
{
    debug($entity);
    die();
}
```